# local param not working in solr 8 but working in solr 5

Tags: solr, lucene, solr5, solr8

I am migrating from solr 5.5 to solr 8.
Query for solr 5.5 looks like -

```
qt=/dismax
product_fields_Ref1=product_concept^279841
sku_and_product_fields_Ref1=silhouette_concept^234256 $product_fields_Ref1
product_phrase_Ref2=pant
concept_with_synonyms_ref1=({!edismax2 qf=$sku_and_product_fields_Ref1     v=$product_phrase_Ref2})
top_concept_query_ref= (+({!maxscore v=$concept_with_synonyms_ref1}) ) 
productQueryRef3=+(+({!query v=$cq})) +( ({!maxscore v=$top_concept_query_ref}) ) 
sq=+{!lucene v=$productQueryRef3}
q={!parent tag=top which=$pq score=max v=$sq}
```

But is giving error on solr 8.0 with error -

> Error from server at http://localhost:8080/products: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Query Field '$product_fields_Ref1' is not a valid field name

If I modify query like this (remove the variable product_fields_Ref1 and append the value directly in sku_and_product_fields_Ref1) -

```
qt=/dismax
sku_and_product_fields_Ref1=silhouette_concept^234256 product_concept^279841
product_phrase_Ref2=pant
concept_with_synonyms_ref1=({!edismax2 qf=$sku_and_product_fields_Ref1     v=$product_phrase_Ref2})
top_concept_query_ref= (+({!maxscore v=$concept_with_synonyms_ref1}) ) 
productQueryRef3=+(+({!query v=$cq})) +( ({!maxscore v=$top_concept_query_ref}) ) 
sq=+{!lucene v=$productQueryRef3}
q={!parent tag=top which=$pq score=max v=$sq}
```

Problem is I can not modify this query since the value of param "product_fields_Ref1" are being compiled from a large number of places.
I am using defType=dismax only.
Can any one guide what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the source code of "org.apache.solr.search.ExtendedDismaxQParser"
and found out the is a new validation check added which DOES NOT allow local parameter in qf field edismax parser (this check has been introduced starting solr 8.0.0).

Check works like this -

any parameter coming in qf MUST match a field in schema (I am not using schema-less mode) of the core. method is

> validateQueryFields(up);

This executes in

> public Query parse() throws SyntaxError { ... }

of

> org.apache.solr.search.ExtendedDismaxQParser

I got this working by creating my own custom parser and removed this validator after overriding the parse() method.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Local Parameters has changed significantly in more recent versions of Solr (see https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/solr-upgrade-notes.html#solr-7-2)

The only way that I have been able to get some of the behavior back is by setting `lucene` as the default parser in `solrconfig.xml` and then passing the local parameters in the query, for example: `q={!dismax qf=$param1}coffee`

I understand that you can get back the old behavior by switching to LuceneMatchVersion 7.1.0 but that change did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks @hector for your time in looking into this. I got the main issue why it only happens in solr 8.0.0 and not in earlier releases. I have put my findings in the answer.